# Convert comma separated substrings of a large string into variant array elements in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

OK, So I'm fairly new to the Qt5 QML framework. This would've been fairly easy in any other language such as Java etc. But I'm unable to accomplish this in QML.

Here's what I want to do: I want to take a long string that I've received from my c++ code separated by commas

```
 property string: "Here,There,That,This"
```

and I want to split it up into separate strings. I've come to understand that you need to use a variant in the sense that I basically have the property

```
property variant stringlist
```

where, stringlist[0]  = "Here" and stringlist[1] = "There" etc.

Does anyone have a suggestion for the code for a function that  I can call to do it. I would like to refrain from needing a javascript addition to create this function. So please do try to suggest a QML centric function, if at all possible.

Comment: As far as I remember, you have access to JavaScript within Qml. Why not use a `split()` ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)) method of JavaScript string?

Comment: True. I just found out and used it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Item{
  property string myString: "Here,There,That,This"
  property variant stringList: myString.split(',')

  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log(stringList[0]); //outputs 'Here'
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I had no idea JavaScript had a split function. Anyway, I needed it to print all elements such that each element was on a separate line. I ended up writing a custom function for it that used your split suggestion. So Thanks :) My problem is solved.

Comment: consider using 'var' instead of deprecated 'variant' as a type for the list property.